# Can art generators imitate art styles of specific works?

Tags: image-generation

I know that they can imitate art styles of specific artists (depending on the training data), as well as generic art styles (anime, oil painting, etc.).

But can they imitate art styles of specific **works** as well? Like the art style of an specific anime like *Sailor Moon*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had pretty good luck with Adobe Firefly learning from one of my Zentangle images in order to mimic my style of drawing Zentangle images.

As such, I believe sharing a Sailor Moon anime image would result in Firefly producing images in the anime style used for Sailor Moon.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Image(s) to image (I2I)

When I think of AI imitating specific works, I think of I2I AIs:

[image: starry night style used on photo]
[Image Source](https://cuicaihao.com/2017/06/21/image-style-transfer-using-convnets-by-tensorflow-windows/)

This image is from a service which uses two images as input: a "style" image and an image to apply that style to. This means you can emulate a "style" regardless of how obscure it is. However, not every "style" image produces good results. It's more like applying a texture to an image, though even then you might not get good results for everything you'd expect. I even struggled when I was trying to apply a grass texture to an image.

Since this type of generic I2I doesn't change the underlying shape of the original image, you can't use it to emulate something like Sailor Moon, since so much of that is how the characters are drawn (e.g., layout of the faces). For that you need something different.

A model trained on a specific work will emulate that work closely. I am not aware of one for Sailor Moon, but I do know that WEBTOON trained models on some of their popular webcomics. The following are some examples from the Korean launch of the "Lookism" filter. (The [Lookism webcomic itself](https://www.webtoons.com/en/drama/lookism/list?title_no=1049&page=1) is freely available online for comparison.) The images almost always match the original art style, sometimes at the expense of resembling the source image. There is a very obvious bias: Many of the screenshots online look like the main character and—worse—everyone came out looking vaguely Korean (like most of the webcomic characters), regardless of what the source image looked like. (This may have been tweaked between the Korean and English launches of the filter, since more recent images had skin tones in shades darker than near-white.)

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Image sources: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lookismcomic/comments/13k6ew4/i_tried_the_lookism_filter_thingy/)

### Text to image (T2I)

When using your average T2I AI to emulate well-known works, you can generally match the style *somewhat*, depending both on the consistency of the training data and how picky you are. For example, AI often can match the character design (often slavishly adhering to it), but when a franchise has either an inconsistent art style or (maybe) a lot of disparate fan art, the actual style itself often gets lost. The Sailor Moon examples below show this. They are recognizably "Sailor Moon" primarily because of the character design. The first one perhaps is close in style to one of the modern Sailor Moon animes, if you're being generous. Prompting for 90s style didn't really do that much for the second image; the eyes are the main change and even that isn't exactly the right style. The styles in these images remind me more of other animes. Perhaps massaging it could get a better result, perhaps not. There is a lot of it left up to chance. This is the middle ground, not terrible, not great.

On the other hand, I've always had success with "in the style of Berserk manga", at least for genre-matching images (mostly horror). This might be at least in part due to the nature of the work. Black and white is easy. Grotesque is a defining feature of many of the illustrations, and that's what AI often does without even trying. The result is never as detailed as the real thing, but it's good enough.

On the opposite side of things, "Lore Olympus" (niche but not extremely so) as a style never creates anything like the original work. It's obvious that the AI was trained on some of it, since it produces people with neon skin/hair colors, but everything else about the images looks very wrong and very much not derivative of the original work.

Much like with the I2I models, much more is possible with specially trained models. For example, who's the Pokémon?

[image]  [image: Barboach]

The other one is from [lambdalabs/sd-pokemon-diffusers](https://huggingface.co/lambdalabs/sd-pokemon-diffusers)

There is a [Sailor Moon tarot card](https://huggingface.co/Duskfallcrew/sailor_moon_tarot_lora) that can be downloaded from GitHub (but I can't tell you how to set it up). The examples mostly show similar character designs in a different art style, but there are some examples of images generated with the art style itself too.

---

### Sailor Moon examples

I used the "anime" style in [Stable Diffusion Web](https://stablediffusionweb.com/#ai-image-generator) for most of these.

"Brown hair sailor moon":

[image]

"Brown hair sailor moon (90s anime)":

[image]

This one was with the "texture" style (somehow getting a more 90s anime style than the "anime" option) but it only half followed my prompt "Brown hair business woman in Sailor moon style" trying to generate anything other than a magical girl didn't really work with the SM prompts):

[image]

None style, "Brown hair sailor moon (90s anime)" using negative prompts for "headband, ponytail"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, if you have a model included that was trained with images of that style. For example well known artists like Van Gogh are implemented in most basic checkpoints. If you try to imitate the style of a not well known artist, the AI will not be able to reproduce it. The generated image will not show any similarities. In this case I recommend to train your own "Lora" (a small model on a specific topic) and include this into your workflow.

If you visit Civitai you can search for Loras. I believe Sailor Moon is well known and you may find Lora for it.